# Help with jQuery string formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Why does the following:

```
$("a").sortable( {
    update:function() {
        var urls = ""; 

        $.map($("a"), function(elt) { 
            urls += "url=" + elt.href + "&";
        });

        $.ajax( {
            url: 'server_side_process_one.aspx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { urls.substr(0,urls.length - 1) },
            success: function() { alert(urls.substr(0,urls.length - 1)); }
        });
    }
});
```

return paths in the following format:

> file:///C:/Program%20Office/OFFICE11/WINWORD.EXE

but the following:

```
$("input:checkbox").live('change', function() { 
    var that = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'server_side_process_two.aspx',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { $(that).attr("id") },
        success: function() { alert($(that).attr("id")); }
    });
});
```

returns path in the following format:?

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE

Any idea how to get both functions to return in the same format?  Preferably both should return in the basic format without all the extra characters, i.e.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE

but not

> file:///C:/Program%20Office/OFFICE11/WINWORD.EXE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you asks for an element's href, you'll get a version of this attribute, processed and cleaned by the browser. So, it really depends on what your aspx script does, but be sure that the URL you're passing to you script through `strURLs` is something with the appropiate URI, like `file:///C:/Program%20Office/OFFICE11/WINWORD.EXE`, and not an incorrect and malformed URL like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE`.

Don't forget that you can see what you're sending to your script using tools like [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) in Firefox.

Good luck!

Comment: In that case, how do I get the second function to return strings in the same format as the first function?

Comment: Maybe using HttpContext.Current.Request.ResolveUrl, but I don't know. It's something that you've to do in the backend, as I see it. In any case, if you want to do this in the front end, refer to this function: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri, and try to extract the path part, and replace the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

This may just "patch" your problem, but you might just let the upper C# function
 return "file:///C:/Program%20Office/OFFICE11/WINWORD.EXE"... and then correct the formatting.

```
string sRtn = "file:///C:/Program%20Office/OFFICE11/WINWORD.EXE";
sRtn = sRtn.Replace("file:///", "");
sRtn = sRtn.Replace("/", "\");
sRtn = sRtn.Replace("%20", " ");
```

Comment: (You may have to escape the backslash character.)